# request.GetResponse() seems to hang up my program

Tags: c#, rest, httprequest

I've been working on a project that gets results from rest servers via httprequests. In this case I tried and succeeded  (Yesterday this same code was working.) in searching for a country and getting it's flag to dipslay.

I've narrowed down that the function "makeRequest" is hanging up my program.

by hanging up i mean that i can't even shut down the form by clicking the "x" on the top right hand corner and have to forcequit by clicking "stop debugg".

Any hints to what i'm doing wrong or has gone wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Code used by form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ApiQueryHandler
{
abstract class QueryCreator
{

    static public string createQueryLandcode(String country)
    {
        string queryStandaard = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/";
        string queryLandCode = "?fields=alpha2Code";
        string query = queryStandaard + country + queryLandCode;
        return query;
    }
    static public string makeRequest(string query)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(query);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
        return responseFromServer;
    }
    static public string createQueryFlag(string country)
    {
        string queryStandaard = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/";
        string queryFlag = "?fields=flag";
        string query = queryStandaard + country + queryFlag;
        return query;
    }
    static public string getSVGFlagUrl(string queryResponseFlag)
    {
        String beginUrl = queryResponseFlag.Substring(10);
        int endUrl = beginUrl.IndexOf('"');
        String url = queryResponseFlag.Substring(10,endUrl);
        return url;
    }
    static public string getPNGFlagUrl(string landCode)
    {
        string PNGUrl = "https://www.countryflags.io/"+landCode+"/flat/64.png";
        return PNGUrl;
    }
    static public string getCode(string queryResponseCode)
    {
        String beginCode = queryResponseCode.Substring(16);
        int endCode = beginCode.IndexOf('"');
        String code = queryResponseCode.Substring(16, endCode);
        return code;
    }
    static public string getCodeShort(string queryResponseCode)
    {
        String beginCode = queryResponseCode.Substring(10);
        int endCode = beginCode.IndexOf('"');
        String code = queryResponseCode.Substring(10, endCode-1);
        return code;
    }
}
```

}

Form code:

```
private void textBoxCounrty_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string country = textBoxCountry.Text;
        string queryLandcode = QueryCreator.createQueryLandcode(country);
        string queryFlag = QueryCreator.createQueryFlag(country);
        try
        {

            string responseLandcode = QueryCreator.makeRequest(queryLandcode);
            string responseFlag = QueryCreator.makeRequest(queryFlag);
            string SVGUrl = QueryCreator.getSVGFlagUrl(responseFlag);
            labelURLQuery.Text = queryLandcode;
            string processedLandcode = QueryCreator.getCode(responseLandcode);
            string PNGUrl = QueryCreator.getPNGFlagUrl(processedLandcode);
            richTextBoxServerResponse.Text = responseLandcode+"\n\n"+processedLandcode+"\n\n"+PNGUrl+"\n\n"+SVGUrl;
            pictureBoxFlag.Load(PNGUrl);
            labelERROR.Text = "";
        }
        catch (WebException)
        {
            labelERROR.Text = "404 not found";
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            labelERROR.Text = "404 not found";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make your request async

```
public async Task<string> makerequest(string query){

}
```

then when you call it use the await modifier

```
string response= await makerequest(yourstring)
```

doing this asyncronously should stop your hanging problem. its important to note you will need t make the calling method async to, as an async call can only be made from an async method.

Comment: thanks for responding so quickly.

so i edited my code:
    -makerequest is now async.
    -the calling method is also async (textBoxCounrty_TextChangedAsync)
    -added await: string responseLandcode = await Makerequest(queryLandcode);
still getting a hangup problem though

Answer (score 0):

it seems that https://restcountries.eu (the rest server i send requests to, doesn't respond)

when using other rest servers like http://countryapi.gear.host my code (original) does work.

Comment: Your code is working for me, maybe a temporary problem with the 'restcountries' server?